# Selecting rows before and after specified row with SQL in python

Tags: python, sql, database

Thank you in advance for any help you give

I am making an API, to retrieve words from a dictionary, so far so good.
One of the requirements to create that API, is when someone sends a request to this endpoint(ex:http://example.com/words/house) , to return that word with all other fields, let me show you more details.

I have this table for words:

```
 word          varchar,
 definition    text,
 pharseology   text,
 etymology     text,
 onomastics    text,
 example       text,
 dictionary_id integer -> FK
```

so basically, when I go to this endpoint, a get a JSON response, with the words,also synonyms, that I have a seperate table pointing to this one in relation one->Many, from words to synonyms,

[image]

Let me go to the point now, the request says that when you request for a word ex "house", there should be a response just like that one the pictures, but also to have a List with all the words that come before that word, and after that word.For example if you search for the word "foot", after words can be foot soldier, foot trafic etc, or before like "eating" or smth.

So I have 2 questions:
1.Should I create a new table and make a relation with word table to show these list of words that specified word has.
2.How do I write a query to get all the rows in top, and bottom of defined word..

Thank you all for your answers,

Comment: To write a query to get all rows in top and bottom you could use the `wild cards` in `sql` or you could opt to do it before it gets to your database, which means you could make use of python regular expressions. You do not have to create a table especially if you need speed, because a new table will only reduce the efficiency and increase the complexity(unnecessarily)

Comment: Do you really want **all** of the words before and after the word for which you are searching?

Comment: @maestro.inc can you help me more specifically, because I am new at this,

Comment: @isaac not really, like 5 or 10, I don't know why I wrote all

Comment: _How do I write a query to get all the rows in top, and bottom of defined word.._ Can you be more specific? Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: @AMC sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I am fetching  words from a dictionary, normally they must be sorted alfabetically in order to get the good result.So when I am retrieving for example a word:house, I need like 5 words that come before that one from dictionary, and 5 others that come after that word.. for ex: word before house can be "eat" and after can be "meet" or something like that.So I need to execute a query, that does that, to return rows before and after called word.

Answer (score 0):

I would not create another table for this. The following query using SQL Server syntax will get you a set number (@WordRange) of words before and after a search word (@SearchWord). If you are using a database other than SQL Server the syntax should be able to be modified to work for you.

The basic idea is to order all of your words alphabetically and assign them a row number. Then you select all of words that are the number of rows before and after your search word based on its row number.

```
CREATE TABLE #Dictionary
(
    ID INT
  , Word VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO #Dictionary
(
    ID
  , Word
)
VALUES (1, 'Elephant'), (2, 'Eel'), (3, 'Armadillo'), (4, 'Armor')
, (5, 'Fence'), (6, 'Park'), (7, 'Mouse'), (8, 'House'), (9, 'Hull')
, (10, 'Sidewalk'), (11, 'Monitor');

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE
    @SearchWord         VARCHAR(50)
  , @SearchWordPosition INT
  , @WordRange          INT;

SET @SearchWord = 'House';
SET @WordRange = 3;

SELECT ID, Word, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Word) rn FROM #Dictionary;

SELECT @SearchWordPosition = x.rn
FROM   (SELECT Word, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Word) rn FROM #Dictionary) x
WHERE  x.Word = @SearchWord;

SELECT
      x.Word
    , x.rn
FROM  (SELECT Word, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Word) rn FROM #Dictionary) x
WHERE x.rn BETWEEN (@SearchWordPosition - @WordRange) AND (@SearchWordPosition + @WordRange);
```

You can see it in action [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=27ac8377b4c232b141516bf5ae318173).